# getting data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, postgis

I have three tables - shop, potato, and tomato (tomato table looks like potato table). The id in the potato table is accually the id of the shop - so the price of the potato in that shop.

```
+----+-------+-----------+
|         potato         |
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | price | date_time |
+----+-------+-----------+

+----+-----+-----+------+------+  
|             shop             |
+----+-----+-----+------+------+
| id | lat | lng | name | geom |
+----+-----+-----+------+------+
```

What I'd like to do, is select all the shops which are max 10 km from some position, along with the tomato and potato price.

Now, I have this query, which can select shops, along with potato price

```
SELECT
    shop.lat,
    shop.lng,
    shop.id,
    potato.date_time AS potato_date,
    potato.price as potato_price 
FROM 
    shop,
    potato 
WHERE
    potato.id = shop.id AND 
    ST_DWithin(
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(xx.xxxxxx yy.yyyyyy)',4326),
        shop.geom,
        10*1000,
        true
    );
```

But I'd like to get also the price of the tomatoes in that shop. How could it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Left JOIN

```
SELECT 
   shop.lat
  , shop.lng
  , shop.id
  , potato.date_time AS potato_date
  , potato.price as potato_price 
  , tomato.date_time as tomato_date
  , tomato.price as tomato_price
FROM shop
LEFT JOIN potato on potato.ID = shop.ID
LEFT JOIN tomato  on tomato.ID =  shop.ID 
WHERE  ST_DWithin(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(xx.xxxxxx yy.yyyyyy)',4326), shop.geom,10*1000, true );
```

If each shop sells tomatoes and potatoes you can use inner join.